# Change colspan based on breakpoint

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to React and I have a table that I hide some columns with CSS media query when the the screen is below certain breakpoint.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
.tdcel {
  display: none;
}
```

It works great, however, in the same table, in a row below I have a cell that's using colspan. Obviously when I hide columns with CSS I need to reduce the colspan as well.

I have an element that's calling a function on click. I was thinking of adding some sort of a check to that function and perhaps count visible cells in the row where the click happens. If I was using jQuery I could do something like this:

```
$(".clickEm").click(function() {
     var ths = $(this),
         par = ths.closest("tr"),
         col = par.find("td:visible").length;

     par.next("tr td").attr("colspan", col); 
}
```

Unfortunately I'm still trying to wrap my mind around React components. Is there a way to accomplish this? Or perhaps I'm overthinking this. Perhaps I can have conditional colspan value based on a viewport size?

```
<td colSpan={5}>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use css-grid or flexbox instead of tables, since it sounds like you have a layout issue here. Those would be purely css solutions.

However, if you need to set the colspan in response to a viewport change, you can always call react functions from window callbacks.

```
class MyComponent(props) extends React.Component {
  state = {
    colspan: 1
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
  }
  resize(){
    // set the state of your component here:
    this.setState({
      colspan: // whatever
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Table>
         <tr>
            <td colSpan={this.state.colspan}>Blah blah blah</td>
         </tr>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

*You may need to change the syntax depending on your variant or flavour of javascript (typescript, classes, whatever.)*

React component class functions are just regular functions that can be called from other functions, like window events. Make sure to remove the function when the component is unmounted, or else you could be left with a memory leak.

Additionally, don't forget that window events like resize can be called multiple times per frame, and react can batch up render calls, so make sure your update and render logic is simple.

Alternatively, there are react components on NPM that respond to window size changes for you. Search for *npm react resize aware*.